# How can i write a method that contains both string and double type? should it be a void or return type method?

Tags: c#, string, methods, double, void

Basically, I want my method to contain(?) both string and double type.
But I don't know how to declare the method, I actually want both as a return type.
It gives me an error if I declare it as a double or as a string.

This is not my original code but it is just an example and a short cut.

This method should print two strings and sum three doubles and print the total of the sum.

```
public static double MethodName ( string A, string B, double n1, double n2, double n3)

{
   double sum;    
   Console.Write(A);    
   Console.Write(B);    
   sum= n1+n2+n3;    
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do, return a double? return a string? What relevance has the code you posted got to do with the question you asked? Did you even research "how to print a string" before asking here?

Comment: Do you need to return both string and double?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Tuple<string, double> MethodName ( string A, string B, double n1, double n2, double n3)
{
   double sum;

   Console.Write(A);

   Console.Write(B);

   sum= n1+n2+n3;

   return new Tuple<string, double>("yourString", sum);
}
```

You can use [**Tuple**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

After that you are taking your values like this:

```
Tuple<string, double> result = MethodName(a,b,n1,n2,n3);
string yourString = result.Item1;
double yourDouble = result.Item2;
```

Comment: thank you i'll try this, but i'm still a student and we didn't learn Tuple yet. I need a very basic way. do you have any other answer?

Comment: @Unknown did you learn `ref` and `out`? if not then make your own class and supply it with values you want

Comment: @Unknown You can define class in which you will have two properties with string and double declaration. After that your method will return this class and you fill the values of the class inside the method.

Comment: Another approach is what @M.kazemAkhgary said but I think this is even more advance than simple class, but if you learn about it you can use it.

Comment: Given that the question states that it should print the strings and the sum of the double, how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Takarii you can click on edited of the question and see what the question look in the begging.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're not returning anything from the function even tho compiler is expecting so as you've defined your function as returning double. In case you want to your last line should be something like

```
...
return sum;
}
```

or if you want it one line shorter then

```
...
return n1+n2+n3;
}
```

Class declaration is fine if you **only** want to return double value.

**EDIT:** In case you want only to write out the sum, change return type to void

```
public static void MethodName ( string A, string B, double n1, double n2, double n3)
```

Otherwise you're making compiler expect something to be returned from your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MethodName (string A, string B, double n1, double n2, double n3)
{
    double sum = n1 + n2 + n3;

    Console.WriteLine(A);
    Console.WriteLine(B);
    Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
}
```

Does exactly what your question asks - Prints the 2 strings, then the sum of the 3 numbers.